# Android mediacodec configureFailed

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Following [this](https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo) i have tried below code to initialize MediaCodec, but it failed! The github hosted project runs without any problem. The updated log is as below

```
01-27 02:02:25.125: I/OMXClient(8956): Using client-side OMX mux.
01-27 02:02:25.140: I/ACodec(8956): setupVideoEncoder succeeded
01-27 02:02:25.140: E/OMXNodeInstance(1910): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
01-27 02:02:25.140: A/ACodec(8956): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:3234 CHECK_EQ( (status_t)OK,mCodec->initNativeWindow()) failed: 0 vs. -2147483648
01-27 02:02:25.140: A/libc(8956): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 8990 (CodecLooper)
```

### The code - Updated after fadden's answer

```
format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 480, 800);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE,400000 );
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);

coder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
//  coder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
if(format != null)
    coder.configure(format, mSurface, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
Log.e("After","Configure");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not configuring all of the [mandatory keys](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q2).

See the [MediaFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html) doc, and note where it says "all keys not marked optional are mandatory".

**Update:**

It's crashing on a failed assertion.  Judging by the line number and the assert message, you're running jb-mr1 (Android 4.2, API 17); source file [is here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-mr1-release/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp).

It's complaining about the "native window", which is another way of saying it doesn't like the surface you're passing in.  Since you're configuring an encoder, you shouldn't be passing in a surface at all -- that's only for rendered output.  Change `mSurface` to `null`.

If you want to provide input through a Surface, you need to use `MediaCodec#createInputSurface()`, which isn't available until API 18.

Comment: I have updated the question, please look on to it!, Thank You

Comment: Hi fadden, is there any way of using `GLSurfaceView` instead of `SurfaceView`, with `MediaCodec`

Comment: A `GLSurfaceView` is a `SurfaceView` with some helper code to do the extra stuff for GL (EGL config selection, management of a separate render thread, etc).  Note one is a subclass of the other.  As far as `MediaCodec` is concerned there's no difference.

Comment: And do you know way co render video onto surface base on Api 16? How can I retrieve video data from codec and show it?

Comment: @JULIIncognito: if you have a new question, you should post it as a new question, not as a comment on a previous answer. Use appropriate tags, e.g. [android] and [mediacodec].