# Decoding with OMX.SEC.vp8.dec and OMX.google.vpx.decoder in Samsung Galaxy Y Duos

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am trying to **decode** a VP8 encoded stream with **OMX.SEC.vp8.dec** and **OMX.google.vpx.decoder** in Samsung Galaxy Y Duos. I am configuring MediaCodec with surface and it shows the following error in the log. I am not sure if there are any MediaCodec or  MediaFormat settings required prior to configuring MediaCodec which are specific to VP8/VP9 codec. The mimeType I am using is video/x-vnd.on2.vp8

```
03-05 16:55:45.231: A/ACodec(3468): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:3333 CHECK_EQ( (status_t)OK,mCodec->initNativeWindow()) failed: 0 vs. -2147483648
03-05 16:57:28.811: A/libc(4165): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 4187 (CodecLooper)
```

**Edit (after fadden's reply): Code**

```
int colorFormat = 0;
int frm_width  = 640;
int frm_height = 360;
int frm_format_choice = 0;
String mimeType = "video/x-vnd.on2.vp8";
String[] types = info.getSupportedTypes();
int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
MediaCodec mediaCodec = null;
MediaFormat mediaFormat = null;

public int  decode_frame() {
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs && codecInfo == null; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo info = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
        if (info.isEncoder()) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] types = info.getSupportedTypes();

        for (int j = 0; j < types.length && !found; j++) {  
            if (types[j].equals(mimeType)) {
                found = true;
                decoder_name = info.getName();
                dec_name.format("%s\n", decoder_name);
                dec_name.flush();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("decoder name " +info.getName());

        if (!found)
            continue;

        codecInfo = info;
    }

    if ( decoder_name.equals("OMX.SEC.vp8.dec") || decoder_name.equals("OMX.google.vpx.decoder") {

        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);

        for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length && colorFormat == 0; i++) {
            int format = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
            switch (format) {
                case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
                case COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanarInterlaced :
                    colorFormat= format;
                    frm_format_choice = format;
                    break;

                case COLOR_TI_Format :
                    colorFormat       = format;
                    frm_format_choice = format;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mimeType);
    mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, frm_width, frm_height);
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, surface, null, 0); // this is where it is crashing.

    if (mediaCodec != null) {
        mediaCodec.start();
        inputBuffers  = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();  
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: I create the surface instance in a test code (as shown below) and I pass to the code where I implement the MediaCodec configure.**

```
import android.view.Surface;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MyClass extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private PlayerThread mPlayer = null;

    //few other initializations

    @Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(this);

    sv.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    setContentView(sv);
}

protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

@Override

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        mPlayer = new PlayerThread(holder.getSurface());
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.interrupt();
    }
}

private class PlayerThread extends Thread {

    private Surface surface;

    public PlayerThread(Surface surface) {

        this.surface = surface;
    }

@Override

public void run() {

    // my implementations

    //This is the method I call to pass the surface where  I am configuring MediaCodec with surface.
    obj_decoder.set_decoder_surface(surface);

    // my implementations

}

}
```

**The edit 1 is a decoder implementation prior to which I pass the surface with this:**

```
Surface surface = null; // Local surface class object.

public void set_decoder_surface(Surface surface)
{
    // Set surface for decoded video.

    this.surface = surface;     

}
```

Comment: Same failure as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325053/android-mediacodec-configurefailed/, but you're decoding rather than encoding.  Can you include the code that configures the decoder in your question?

Comment: @fadden Thank You for the reply . I have posted the code.

Comment: You're passing a surface to `configure()`.  How was that created?  The assertion failure is saying that it doesn't like the surface it was given.

Answer (score 0):

I think you migth be missed some of the params.
Color format is important here

```
  format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
```

Or if you want to use YUV output buffer you do not need to specify surface.

There are some others, not sure if they matters.

Also, code you shared does not have anything about surface creation, hope it is correct one

Comment: Color format doesn't really matter for decoding -- the decoder gives you whatever it feels like.